# Like expression doesn't work mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm having a problem with a MySQL query.  When I trying to filter the query using one of the columns of the query it's says there are no rows.

```
SELECT `Voucher`.`id`, `Voucher`.`name`, `Voucher`.`batch`, `Voucher`.`status`, `Voucher`.`perc_time_used`, `Voucher`.`perc_data_used`, 
`Voucher`.`last_accept_time`, `Voucher`.`last_reject_time`, `Voucher`.`last_accept_nas`, `Voucher`.`last_reject_nas`, `Voucher`.`last_reject_message`, 
`Voucher`.`user_id`, `Voucher`.`created`, `Voucher`. `modified`, `Voucher`.`extra_name`, `Voucher`.`extra_value`, `Voucher`.`password`, 
`Voucher`.`realm`, `Voucher`.`realm_id`, `Voucher`.`profile`, `Voucher`.`profile_id`, `Voucher`.`expire`, `Voucher`.`time_valid`, `Voucher`.`data_used`, 
`Voucher`.`data_cap`, `Voucher`.`time_used`, `Voucher`.`time_cap`, 
(SELECT voucher_values.value FROM voucher_values WHERE voucher_values.attribute = 'gender' AND voucher_values.voucher_id = `Voucher`.`id`) AS `gender`, 
(SELECT voucher_values.value FROM voucher_values WHERE voucher_values.attribute = 'residence' AND voucher_values.voucher_id = `Voucher`.`id`) AS `residence`, 
(SELECT voucher_values.value FROM voucher_values WHERE voucher_values.attribute = 'age' AND voucher_values.voucher_id = `Voucher`.`id`) AS `age`, 
(SELECT voucher_values.value FROM voucher_values WHERE voucher_values.attribute = 'nationality' AND voucher_values.voucher_id = `Voucher`.`id`) AS `nationality`, 
(SELECT voucher_values.value FROM voucher_values WHERE voucher_values.attribute = 'email' AND voucher_values.voucher_id = `Voucher`.`id`) AS `email`, 
(SELECT voucher_values.value FROM voucher_values WHERE voucher_values.attribute = 'facebookid' AND voucher_values.voucher_id = `Voucher`.`id`) AS `facebookid`, 
(SELECT voucher_values.value FROM voucher_values WHERE voucher_values.attribute = 'googleid' AND voucher_values.voucher_id = `Voucher`.`id`) AS `googleid`, 
(SELECT voucher_values.value FROM voucher_values WHERE voucher_values.attribute = 'interests' AND voucher_values.voucher_id = `Voucher`.`id`) AS `interests`, 
`User`.`id`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`token`, `User`.`name`, `User`.`surname`, `User`.`address`, `User`.`phone`, `User.email`,
`User`.`active`, `User`.`monitor`, `User`.`country_id`, `User`.`group_id`, `User`.`language_id`, `User`.`parent_id`, `User`.`lft`, `User`.`rght`, 
`User`.`created`, `User`.`modified` 
FROM `rd`.`vouchers` AS `Voucher` LEFT JOIN `rd`.`users` AS `User` ON (`Voucher`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`)
WHERE `User`.`id` IN (58,59) AND `email` LIKE '%%' ORDER BY Voucher.name DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```

My problem is on the `WHERE` clause - more specifically on `email LIKE '%%'`. When I try to put something between the percentages the query returns no rows. And I know the character that I put in is on that field.

Comment: what do you mean with %% ?

Comment: %% is all the emails I know this unecessary if I take it out it will do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if that's what causing the issue, but when `LEFT JOIN`ing , condition on the right table of a `LEFT JOIN` should be specified only inside the `ON` clause.

```
FROM rd.vouchers AS Voucher
LEFT JOIN rd.users AS User 
ON (Voucher.user_id = User.id AND User.id IN (58,59))
WHERE email LIKE '%String%'
ORDER BY Voucher.name DESC
 LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```

If `Email` column belongs to `users` table, then that's the problem and you should also add it to the `ON` clause :

```
ON (Voucher.user_id = User.id
    AND User.id IN (58,59)
    AND email LIKE '%String%')
ORDER BY Voucher.name DESC
 LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: the email column doesn´t belong to users it belongs to voucher_values as you can see in subquery inside of the query: (SELECT voucher_values.value FROM voucher_values WHERE voucher_values.attribute = 'email' AND voucher_values.voucher_id = `Voucher`.`id`) AS `email`

Comment: Ohh it's a correlated query, wrap the query with another select and move the `like` outside.

Answer (score 0):

How many rows are returned when it is in this state? (without the LIMIT)
What is the character you are putting between the %%?

Comment: the response is all lines that i want without the character between %%. the character i put in is an 's'